# Setting up Wordpress on Webmin

Tags: apache, installation

Thanks for taking the time to check this post out.

I've set up a local Wordpress installation on my Ubuntu (10.04 LTS) which currently works.

However, I wanted to get it to work on my webmin (1.580) as an apache webserver. I was wondering if anyone has done this before and how they got it to work.

What I've done so far on my webmin:
- Created a new virtual host (port 3251, chosen randomly) with SSL option enabled
- Set up port under global configuration
- Applied and restarted Apache webserver

When I tested this out - I received an Internal server error 
so I assumed I needed to update the wp_options - so I set the option values of my 'siteurl' and 'home' to the port.  However i still received the same error.

I'm wondering what else I needed to do to get this to work.

#### Apache error log:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.

It looks like there's a loop somewhere?

#### Rewrite log (`RewriteLogLevel 3`):

```
(2) [perdir /home/site/Website/web/] trying to replace prefix /home/site/Website/web/ with /web/
192.168.1.21 - - [06/Jul/2012:14:06:08 --0700] [guest-PC/sid#7f036c544db0][rid#7f036ca65790/initial/redir#10] 
(1) [perdir /home/site/Website/web/] internal redirect with /web/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved from two parts:
The wp_options for 'home' and 'siteurl' needs to be set. Which I had already done.
However, the next part was to chance the .htaccess to remove the trailing backslash since webmin already has that handled.